# Update JSON-type column with jsonb_set()

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

I tried to update `data` column (with type of `json`) of `books` table by `jsonb_set`

```
UPDATE books 
SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{borrowers}', '[{"name":"john doe","time":"1:00PM"}]')
WHERE id= 'some_id';
```

And encountered this error:

```
> ERROR:  function jsonb_set(json, unknown, unknown) does not exist
```

I found that in the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html), `jsonb_set` only work with `jsonb` type

> `jsonb_set(target jsonb, path text[], new_value jsonb [, create_missing boolean])`

But I could not have privilege to update the column type to `jsonb`. So how could I resolve in this case?

Answer (score 4):

Came up with a simple trick by type casting

```
UPDATE books 
SET data = jsonb_set(data::jsonb, '{borrowers}', '[{"name":"john doe","time":"1:00PM"}]')
WHERE id= 'some_id';
```